# .slice.call vs .push in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

One of my friends uses `[].slice.call()` to fill an array with matched elements.

I wonder how this works. I just know the `Array.prototype.push` to fill an array.

Also I have seen there is a difference in both techniques to fill an array.

So my questions are:

- How does `Array.prototype.slice` help to fill an array?
- What are the roles of `Array.prototype.slice` and `Array.prototype.push` to make objects and arrays?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbLWX/)

```
var arr=[];
var arr=[].slice.call($('[id^=name]'));
//arr.push($('[id^=name]'))
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.slice()` method of arrays returns a *shallow copy* of a portion of an array. It's written as a method on the Array prototype, so the array it operates on is the array in whose context it's invoked. Normally that'd be something like this:

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice(2, 4);
```

When you call the `.slice()` method with `.call()`, you can control the value of `this` explicitly.  In your friend's code, he's passing a jQuery object as the `this` value. Because there are no other parameters, `.slice()` returns a shallow copy of the jQuery object in its entirety, as a new array. (Like some other similar methods, `.slice()` will work on anything that looks like an array: basically, anything that has a `.length` property and numerically-indexed properties of interest. A jQuery object fits that description.)

However, since jQuery already has a built-in method to return a plain array of all matched elements, your friend should not bother doing that anymore:

```
var plainArray = $('[id^=name]').get();
```

That does exactly the same thing. Using `.slice()` isn't *wrong*, but it's kind-of pointless.

Comment: Ha ha thanks - you must have been away because there are weeds and stuff growing on me here

Comment: Somebody should compile a book of Mr. Crowder's excellent deleted answers :)

Answer (score 3):

How about `$('[id^=name]').get()`?

The `[].slice.call` method leverages the array-like `length` and numeric key properties of jQuery objects to re-use the intentionally generic methods of `Array.prototype`.  The method `Array.prototype.slice` is documented by the standard to return a new `Array` object by performing a specific algorithm that accesses numeric-keyed properties in sequence of the `this` object - regardless of its type - assigning the values to sequential elements of the new `Array`.

I wouldn't use either approach, because jQuery has `get()`, which is documented to return an array of the elements matched.  Why use a more obscure or less direct approach?

Comment: Thank, but I just want to my question to be answered

Answer (score 1):

I does't have any specified reason for this case, but The thing i know is, .slice() also used to create another instance of an array, And here the slice add a space to its instance because it have no parameters.

Javascript is the language where you perform a Single operations in 1000's of different ways ! its depend on your choice!
But, We must have to follow the syntax that is made for particular operation.